# Ruby database structure for the days of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

Ok So we have a table called Schedule Model and on a Day model which has the days of the week. We also have a join table so a Schedule could have many days.

We are thinking of removing the Day model and the Join table and putting a flag in the Schedule table with 7 booleans. Any idea if there is a better way to achieve this in Ruby with out cluttering the schedule table with 7 booleans

Comment: Have a look at [the flag_shih_tzu gem](https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu). It would help you set up a bit field for the days `has_flags 1=>'monday', 2=>'tuesday'...` and provide convenience accessors for each day. Might be a fit for your use case, however there will certainly be even better solutions out there, so keep looking!

Comment: I'd stick with separate Boolean or single char fields, because the DBM will be able to quickly locate a particular day or days. As a second method, I'd use an integer field and then use bits to show whether a particular day is set. The DBM should be able to `AND` and `OR` bits very quickly. Putting the Booleans in the Schedule table is a natural fit and should result in very fast access.

Comment: @theTinMan: But bit twiddling inside a database tends to lead to table scans. If your database supports indexing expression results (which at least PostgreSQL does) then you can index bit fields but the indexes will kill the space gain of using bits and AR will fight you. I'll agree with you on `serialize` though, that's an awful kludge that should be harder to use in order to discourage you from doing it.

Comment: @muistooshort, that's true about the table scans. (And, +1 for mentioning PostgreSQL's support.) And +1 * 2 for mentioning how serializing is a kludge; It makes me scream when I see it because I think of the poor overworked DBM. :-)